# Strategies for migrating from MVC2 to MVC3/Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a fairly large MVC2 site and would like to start incorporating MVC3 to take advantage of the Razor view engine.  I've seen the [Upgrade Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx), but that seems to focus on converting my project (already done), not my pages.  The [Telerik conversion tool](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter) is interesting, but forces a wholesale move to MVC3. I would prefer a staggered move, where new pages are developed in Razor and old pages are converted when necessary / as time permits.

So, what strategies are there to migrate from MVC2 to MVC3? How do you mix the two -- duplicate your Master Pages/Layouts and live with it till you're done converting?